# FLUTTER - Accessing all type of files from Download directory

Tags: android, flutter

I'm currently working on a Flutter project where I need to access various types of data, including zip files, PDFs, and directories. However, I'm encountering difficulties in accessing these specific file types using the `dart:io` package in Flutter.

I've followed the official documentation for the dart:io package and used the Directory and File classes to list files within a directory. While I can successfully list directories, I'm unable to access zip files, PDFs, and even zipped directories. I have confirmed that the file paths are correct.

Here's an example of the code I'm using to list files within a directory:

```
    Future<void> checkDirectoryForNewFiles() async {
        Directory directory = Directory('/storage/emulated/0/Download');
        List<FileSystemEntity> files = directory.listSync();
    
        // Process the files as needed
        for (FileSystemEntity file in files) {
    
            // Handle files
            print(file.path);
            // Do something with the file
            if (file.uri != null && RegExp(r'\btakeout\b').hasMatch(file.uri.toString())) {
              print(await showDataAlert());
            }
          
        }
    }
```

can you help?

Comment: Android version of used device(s). ? Did your app create those files?

Comment: `While I can successfully list directories, I'm unable to access zip files` ? Do you mean: `While I can successfully list directories, I'm unable to list zip files`?

Comment: Sorry, dont understand a word.

Comment: I am able to list regular directories, but I am unable to list zipped directories. The same issue is observed for all types of files, such as PDF, MP3, and TXT.

Comment: No as you use the same words as before.

Answer (score 0):

> > I'm encountering difficulties in accessing these specific file types using the dart:io package in Flutter.

We think that you only encounter difficulties in listing files that do not belong to your app on Android 11+ devices.

Comment: Maybe it is this problem, that has sense...do you know how to bypass it? Maybe adding some permissions to the Manifest?

Comment: Well first tell if those missing files are created by your app yes or no. And Android version.

Comment: No and Android 12+

Comment: Then thats the point. Your app cannot list files then it did not create.

Comment: why? Because I don t have permission?

Answer (score 0):

Even I was getting the issue. After sime researching I found out that after android 11 and above the [permission to the storage is limited by default](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage). You can solve the issue by just shifting the Downloads directory (".../0/Downloads/") to External Directory which you can get from path_provider package.